# How to bind a image in Label in WPF using pure code?

Tags: wpf, image, label, bind

I am new to WPF, here I am making a jigsaw game but encountering a problem: I just don't know how to let a image show in a Label in pure code (in XAML, I can do it.), I have searched google a lot but seems that no releated articles regarding this topic. Anyone can help me on this? thx.

My Code Sample:

```
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Width = 120;
        lbl.Height = 120;
        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen);

        BitmapImage myImageSource = new BitmapImage();
        myImageSource.BeginInit(); 
        myImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("Images/test.png",UriKind.Relative); 
        myImageSource.EndInit();

        lbl.Background.SetValue(ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty, myImageSource);

        myGridContainer.Children.Add(lbl);
```

well, this code sample can't work. why ? any comment or answer from you will be appreciated , thx.

Comment: I think it's because you've used a SolidColorBrush instead of an ImageBrush. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx

Comment: @Gishu well, when I comment out the code : lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen); , it throws me the exception at lbl.Background.SetValue(ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty, myImageSource);  as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: use `lbl.Background = new ImageBrush()` instead. Getting a good WPF book like 'Programming WPF' by IanGriffith, Chris Sells.. will help you code faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BindingOperations.SetBinding to data-bind a DependencyProperty to its source.

See also: [How can I create a tiled image in code that is also data-bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749325)

Comment: Sorry, I am a newer, just can't get any options from the article you recommand. I just don't know how to use the BindingOperations.

Comment: I have changed some of the cotent, Would you pls have a look? thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586028 I thing you would need to bind the Source property of a Image (which can be the content of the label). To set data bindings in code, refer to this MSDN How to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx. Now you just need to use the knowledge to bind Image.Source instead of TextBlock.TextProperty as in the article.